# TickScale from ttkwidgets jumps to 0 or 1 when clicking on it

Tags: python, tkinter, ttkwidgets

When clicking in the TickScale widget it jumps to 1 or 0 depending on the relative position of the cursor and the slider. How can I suppress this behavior?

Changing the **resolution** option does not make the jump smaller...

```
import ttkwidgets as ttkw
      
      ...

class GuiPart:

    def __init__(self, master):
    
        ... 

        self.scale = ttkw.TickScale(self.frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, resolution= 0.1)
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal example of how you create the TickScale, for me changing the resolution works

Answer (score 0):

My workaround was to set the **from** and **to** options to 0 and 100

```
scale = ttk.Scale(self.frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, from_ = 0, to_ = 100)
```

and just do

```
var = scale.get()/100
```